# Hide SubGrid New Button button based on Parent status

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

i try to hide the + button from Subgrid invoice detail in the entity invoice when statuscode is equal to 181510000 but it not worked any help!!
[image]
[image]

i do following:

1)create Javascript:

```js
function hideSub(executionContext)
{
 var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
 if(formContext.getAttribute("statecode").getValue() == 181510000)
  return true;
 else 
  return false;
}
```

2) i add Enable rule[image]
3) i add the rule to the command
[image]

Comment: can you put a debugger to see if that function triggered at all?

Comment: did you try hiding button without any Logic, meaning just try to hide it with right click Hide, See if this works and then go step by step. Many times it happen we work on button which is different than we expect.